# Is it possible to embed remote mp4 video using facebook graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, video, post, embed

I'm trying to embed an mp4 video from an external website onto a wall post using the API.  The result should look the same as when a user uploads a video: there is a thumbnail from the video displayed, and clicking on it plays the video inline.

From the documentation, I expected this to work:

```
$ curl -k -F 'access_token=BAAC8...' \
    -F 'message=A test' \
    -F 'source=<full url of mp4>' \
    https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed
```

but the source argument just results in the domain name from the URL being displayed, and it's not even a link.

I tried using link= instead of source=.  At least it results in a clickable link, but the content is the URL, and clicking on it displays the video in a new page.

I also tried posting to https://graph.facebook.com/me/links, but the result was the same as using links= and /me/feed.

I've found similar questions where the answers suggest it's possible with youtube videos and/or swf files, but they seem to be doing exactly what I've already tried.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Have you gotten anywhere with this @jim? As far as I can tell, you still cannot upload videos to the graph api from a url. Also, they now have created a special subdomain for handling video graph-video.facebook.com